Why coupon form not work in all hooks of checkout?
I need to move coupon form on chckout at another place. Do it via hook override:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'bbloomer_checkout_coupon_below_payment_button' );
function bbloomer_checkout_coupon_below_payment_button() {
   echo '<hr>';
   woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form();
}

In all hooks of checkout coupon field MOVED - But NOT in ALL hooks works!
For ex - when move to woocommerce_checkout_order_review, woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review - it's just submit the checkout form (not coupon)
But im some place it's works themself corrct - for ex. woocommerce_review_order_before_submit
Why not in all place form work correct?
